# Background task in windows store App

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, background-process

I'm developing an application which communicates with **REST** services. I want to implement a background process/task which continues to run throughout the life-cycle of the application.

Expected behavior of background process/task is it should monitor/listen the local DB(**Sqlite**) and whenever a record added to local db it sends it to Server using Restful APIs. Kinda synchronization.

It may happen that the application gets disconnected from internet/network and let's assume few records were not synced due to N/W unavailability. So next time whenever N/W gets up the *background process* starts sending pending records to the server.

---

**Question**: How can i achieve this? Do i need to do some threading? 
Reference links are welcomed :-)

Comment: I am not sure if a watchdog timer is what you want, but it maybe leads you to the solution. I would prefer a better solution in terms of event-driven handling. Maybe you can implement events for your sqlite db and trigger them at any time you need it. It is way less performance bound and easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **Windows Runtime Component** project fo background tasking. Follow this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks).

I think this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/update-a-live-tile-from-a-background-task) is similar to your requirements :

Be aware, that a Windows Runtime Component has [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx), check "Declaring types in Windows Runtime Components" section for example.